# How to train some model with video data

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I trained my model with image like this:

```
class ASDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, client_file: str, imposter_file: str, transforms=None):
        with open(client_file, "r") as f:
            client_files = f.read().splitlines()
        with open(imposter_file, "r") as f:
            imposter_files = f.read().splitlines()
        self.labels = torch.cat((torch.ones(len(client_files)), torch.zeros(len(imposter_files))))
        self.imgs = client_files + imposter_files
        self.transforms = transforms

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.imgs)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img_name = self.imgs[idx]
        img = Image.open(img_name)
        label = self.labels[idx]
        if self.transforms:
            img = self.transforms(img)
        return img, label

train_dataset = ASDataset(client_file="/kaggle/input/nuaaaa/raw/client_train_raw.txt", imposter_file="/kaggle/input/nuaaaa/raw/imposter_train_raw.txt", transforms=preprocess)
val_dataset = ASDataset(client_file="/kaggle/input/nuaaaa/raw/client_test_raw.txt", imposter_file="/kaggle/input/nuaaaa/raw/imposter_test_raw.txt", transforms=preprocess)

# Create data loaders
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=8, shuffle=True)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=8, shuffle=False)
```

But now I have video data and as I understand I need to change `class ASDataset`. I tried different variants. For example:

```
class VideoDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, video_file: str, label: int, transforms=None):
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(video_file)
        self.label = label
        self.transforms = transforms

    def __len__(self):
        return int(self.video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        self.video.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, idx)
        success, frame = self.video.read()
        if not success:
            raise ValueError("Failed to read frame")
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)  # Convert to RGB
        if self.transforms:
            frame = self.transforms(frame)
        return frame, self.label
```

But no one give me result.
Help me please, how can I use video data fot training?

Example of data client_train_raw.txt:

```
/kaggle/input/dfdcdfdc/DFDCDFDC/dbnygxtwek.mp4
/kaggle/input/dfdcdfdc/DFDCDFDC/dbtbbhakdv.mp4
/kaggle/input/dfdcdfdc/DFDCDFDC/ddepeddixj.mp4
```